# Java Private constructor in Junits

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, constructor, private-constructor

I've a class with few constants declared, initialized and I also have a private constructor. 
For some reasons I'm writing Junits to achieve the code coverage.
Here I have used constructor.setaccessible(true) and I have initialized the class.

In the assert statement I'm expecting the length of the constructor to be 1.

I've achieved 100% code coverage for this class. But I'm quite not sure how. Can anyone please throw some light on this?

```
public class CommonConstants {
  public static final String ABC= "ABC";
  public static final String XYZ= "XYZ";

  private CommonConstants() {}
}

@Test
public void stringTest() {
     final Constructor<?>[] constructors = CommonConstants.class.getDeclaredConstructors();
     constructors[0].setAccessible(true);
     try {
          CommonConstants cc = (CommonConstants) constructors[0].newInstance();
     } catch (InstantiationException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
     }
     Assert.assertEquals(1, constructors.length);
  }
```

Comment: Could you share your code and the corresponding test code?

Comment: @DirkHerrmann this is how the code looks. Please find it in the edited section of the question.

Comment: What surprises you?  Your class under test has no code besides the constructor and the static members.  There are no conditions within the constructor - that means, calling it once will cover it completely.  And, your test is calling it, so I would not expect anything else than 100% coverage here.  What is suspicious is the way you have written the test code: This contains checks that should not be needed if the test is properly written.  Plus, whether calling the private constructor this way might also be subject to debate - but these are different stories.